# Random files appeared , what to do?

Tags: windows

It seems some random files appeared in my `C:` drive:

[image: file listing]

Not sure how to proceed, it seems they showed up after installing xampp, however they are not in the xampp folder, and it says **Microsoft Corp** in their description. How should I handle them? As in, should I delete them or keep them there?

Comment: All the files in the image appeared? Or some were already there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safety delete those files. It is a bug from the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributible installer (See [KB950683](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950683)).

Answer (score 0):

Something, probably a "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable" or similar unpacked its installer to the root of your C: drive.  If this was included as part of a bigger installer, that installer may have specified "c:\" as a temporary directory, or the installer was run with "c:\" as the current directory.

It's harmless.  I would advise against deleting the files as you may get a random MSI pop-up sometime in the future that's looking for files there.